# Automatic Generic callback

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following code snippet :

```js
// Library code

type Forced = {
    name: string;
}

const funcExample = <T extends Forced,>(
    values: T[],
    defaultValue: (name: string) => T,
): T[] => {
    // Do some operations...
    const result = values.map( (value) => {
        // Yay, I can access my .name attribute on a Generic.
        // That's what I want
        if (value.name === "wrong_condition_that_leads_to_default") {
            const res = defaultValue(value.name)
            return res;
        }
        const res2 = {...value}
        return res2;
    })

    return result;
}
```

```js
// User code

type Animal = {
    name: string,
    parent: string,
}

const animals: Animal[] = [
    {name: "A", parent: "Y"},
    {name: "B", parent: "X"},
    {name: "C", parent: "Z"},
]

const myVar = funcExample(
    animals,
    (name) => {
        const t = {
            name: name,
            parent: "foo",
        };
        return t;
    }
)
// Type of myVar is...
// const myVar: {
//     name: string;
//     parent: string;
// }[]

// I want it to be...
// const myVar: Animal[]
```

I have found a solution that consists of calling my generic `funcExample` specifying the correct type in the callback, such as...

```js
const myVar = funcExample(
    animals,
    (name) => {
        const t: Animal = {
            name: name,
            parent: "foo",
        };
        return t;
    }
)
// Now the type is great, automaticly.
// const myVar: Animal[]
```

Is there a way of having it mapped automaticly ?

The problem I want to solve today is that I want typescript to make the following error impossible to happen : Defining a callback that doesn't respect the signature I have provided in my `defaultValue: (name: string) => T` type signature.

EDIT :

For instance, this wouldn't throw an error if I do not implement the key `parent: string`. But I want it to throw an error.

```js
const myVar = funcExample(
    animals,
    (name) => {
        const t = {
            name: name,
        };
        return t;
    }
)
```

Comment: You want `T` not to be inferred from the return type of `defaultValue`; that is, you want  the `T` in `(name: string) => T` to be a *noninferential type parameter usage* as described in [ms/TS#14829](https://tsplay.dev/m3KAkm). There are various approaches to doing that, which work for some use cases.  [Here's one](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining (or find an appropriate dupe target). If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks so much, yeah, the workaround `<T extends Forced, U extends T>` you found is AWESOME. You deserve your 25 points :) I let you write an answer

Comment: @jcalz if you have a suggestion for the title of the question so that it may help others and lead to your answers as duplicate, I'm open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `T` is currently being inferred from the `defaultValue` argument, which means that if you return a `Forced` then TS will infer that `T` is `Forced` instead of something narrower like `Animal`, regardless of what is passed in as the `values` argument.

You want `T` to be inferred only from the `values` argument and *not* from the `defaulValue` argument.  In other words, in the type `(name: string) => T` of `defaultValue`, you want `T` to be a *non-inferential type parameter usage*.  This is the subject of the feature request [microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829).

Currently there is no built-in way to do this, but the GitHub issue presents various user-implemented approaches that work for at least some use cases.  One way to do it is to "lower the priority" of the relevant type parameter usage by [intersecting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) it with the empty object type `{}`, as mentioned [in this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-320754731).  That gives you

```
const funcExample = <T extends Forced>(
  values: T[],
  defaultValue: (name: string) => (T & {}),
): T[] => ⋯
```

Or, you could introduce a new type parameter `U` [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `T`, and use `U` as a non-inferential version of `T`, as mentioned [in this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-288902999):

```
const funcExample = <T extends Forced, U extends T>(
  values: T[],
  defaultValue: (name: string) => U,
): T[] =>
```

There are other approaches too, but I'll stop there; interested parties should consult microsoft/TypeScript#14829.  Anyway, both of those work for your examples:

```
const myVarGood = funcExample(
  animals,
  (name) => {
    return { name: name, parent: "foo", };
  }
);
// const myVarGood: Animal[]
```

Now the output is inferred as `Animal[]`.  And you'll get an error in the desired place as well:

```
const myVarBad = funcExample(
  animals,
  (name) => { // error! 
    return { name: name, };
  }
)
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&ts=5.3.2#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAMQPYCcDGMAmcC8cDeoccAdgIYC2MAXHAM5goCWJA5gNygC+okscAQRJMKZADa4CRUpRr1GLVgBppUMihgkwtBszYqQPEKDRISDOGWGixdWkJHiA2gF1JT6fhlVaAIgG+SnBqGlp+AJq+cFwGxF7kPnC+AEKBweqa2kkAGlExnt5yvgDCaSGZfgBaeQYuoKAJMHRqGHAAMkgA7jAoAArMqEyQUiDEpuZgcABmAK4kaACiAB6UUGLweAA8ACpwMEtgmph0iKgYmAB8ABTSxABu4jNNtNuuscRwmDBTZDNiYAA1R5yK6NHQKNgASlwFzgV12ADICFxIe9IS9XDCRh84AB6XFwAAiSHoSCocCQsBQZDATDMdAAdEzbnBxhYNHQ-pM8A8xE9GaIoFcrryntCcLDCKMcXiCeEyBAggBJVlWSxoDB0E4UCBwBmNSxgBQAIxmhwpJEscAA4poekw0AyWcR8XBtgALGkAchOnU9kxVnSsYGdcCYUzhopg+tkuBweF8nRQZlYAH1xpghnSSKmwP7U+syMdc0hU18flzfNCpTKPmzJhzJOXfv8gXyYCLgTGqJDQ8QNGAZihLRzONKcUZa-W4ByAEySLxMhlR6KhgdDkdNWdjie94zjmcwQfDw+c-471f76TTnVAlDWpBIbB4WbzZardY3A9WRy2d7EUFZHFSU1yPDcCEKWhGiCcowiSKZHzSLgL2ISc4EhC9XRvCA7wfJ97GsZw6n3MZ6UmW91GSItJFfRYVgoNYOxZH8bDof84UaYCINdHpkxQABCOBQOPS14lkKDZCCZCWTQvd6kMEwyOmOY6I-DY4B2PYDiOE5kHQLAggAVS0w4SGON1rmkKM7DdN5pGbLk2yeWhAMSXRFC4wyDHRWy3AlbFZSJEk6DJeBKR6Gls0ZZlpWnDkuUkayGUFYUoy4msPldeVFTgFU0DVMgNSabVdW7eAaRNM0wstMgbTtZhHRZV0PW9X1-VyuAgy0Flw0jLsDXjBMkxTdMzEzWkzFzfNC2LMBSwc-4qwCnE4qaJtvhbQFgU7dsyr3Wt1xPUcZJZVa6HnPBFyZFc0P7MCjq3C8UXku6RNPLkxyMUBXUMugelZJ8YHk7DcMfZ9lLfejGK-YgWPENjpFcmB0pZQ7RMgwoYIyODfAQpAkKe0AMO+gkQfUPDMAI39XGBpSKJQKjwdo98GM-aQ4b-RHOKxLweJQPjBNR+70bBTHokJkA9yAA)